# ffmpeg: how to resample audio file

Tags: audio, ffmpeg

I need to convert a 44KHz *stero* **m4a** audio file to 22KHz *mono* **mp3** VBR file, how can I do that with ffmpeg on linux terminal?  Thanks.

Comment: Use `ffmpeg -i in.m4a -ac 1 -ar 22050 out.mp3`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[Gyan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5726027/gyan)'s comment is what I want, here is the full command line:

```
ffmpeg -i in.m4a -ac 1 -ar 22050 -c:a libmp3lame -q:a 9 out.mp3
```

with the option for VBR encoding.  The number after `-q:a` specifies encoding quality (bitrate), with `0` being the best quality (largest file) and `9` being the worst quality (smallest file).

Here is the document on [ffmpeg wiki](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Encode/MP3).